# What does "how old it the fight" mean?

Tags: error

"BBC news" YouTube channel published a video about Kashmir. It was titled as:

Kashmir: How old it the fight ?

Does that make sense or there was "is" instead of "it"?

Comment: Link to the video - https://youtu.be/WpthjMoI77I

Comment: As you say. A finger slipped when someone typed the caption.

Comment: looks like a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I typo to me. I suspect that the title was supposed to be *Kashmir: How Old is the Fight?*

In that case, the title implies that the video teaches or talks about the history of the conflict and how it began.